# How to download folder of amazon s3 using asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to download folder from amazon s3 such that it contains all its subfolders and files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. there is no such thing as folder in amazon S3 but bucket
2. you can look examples using the .NET sdk http://docs.ceph.com/docs/hammer/radosgw/s3/csharp/

you will need to list the elements of the bucket

```
ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
request.BucketName = "my-new-bucket";
ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);
```

and to download one object from the bucket

```
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
request.BucketName = "my-bucket";
request.Key        = "my-file.ext"
GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request);
response.WriteResponseStreamToFile("<path\\to\\download\\my\\file.ext>");
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.